# How to deserialize Arraylist items into concrete type using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, deserialization, system.text.json

I have below Test classes

```
public class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }            
    public ArrayList list { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.MyProperty = 1;
    e1.Name = "Yash";
    Employee e2 = new Employee();
    e2.MyProperty = 1;
    e2.Name = "Yash";
    Test t = new Test();
    t.list = new ArrayList();
    t.list.Add(e1);
    t.list.Add(e2);
    string text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(t);
    Test t2 = new Test();
    t2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(text);
}
```

When I deserialize with Newtonsoft I see JObjects instead of Employee objects in the array List. I was able to solve this using Newtonsoft.Json by creating ArrayList converter.

However, the same is not possible with System.text.Json.  How can I deserialize this ArrayList with System.Text.Json?  It's age old code I need to support, and every time I deserialize an ArrayList I know which object type it is expected to contain.

Comment: My advice: don't use `ArrayList`. If you need a list of things, then use a list of things, for example `List<Employee>`

Comment: @DavidG yeah thats the best way to do if we are starting something new but I have with live with what I have at the moment. Unfortunately I can't change to List<Employee> for various reasons within my project.

Comment: If you can convert the `list` property to a generic instead of `ArrayList` that would be ideal. If not, you can create custom serializers in System.Text.Json. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622527/how-to-force-a-single-property-to-format-as-a-date-and-not-a-date-time-when-seri/67623022#67623022

Comment: @JackA. Employee is just one example here but I have many such scenarios, above example is specific for `DateTimeOffset` object, so If I want to write this for `Manager`, `Employee`,`Admin` etc objects, do I need to create multiple converters?  Can I not create one generic converter like how we are able to do with Newtonsoft.Json like we did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564842/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-arraylist-of-arrays-by-using-json-net

Comment: Your custom converter will be based on `JsonConverter<ArrayList>`, so internally you can inspect the item type.

Comment: *the same is not possible with System.text.Json* -- why not?  It certainly should be possible.  What have you tried?  Do you know the types of objects to expect in your `ArrayList` in advance, or are the contents polymorphic and might contain anything?

Comment: Also, why are you even using `ArrayList` in 2021?  In .NET 2.0 and later you should always prefer `List<T>`.  If you can modify your model to be typed -- i.e. `public List<Employee> list` -- your life will be much easier.  For confirmation, see [c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/725459/3744182) for which the answer is, *The main time to use ArrayList is in .NET 1.1.  Other than that, `List<T>` all the way.*

Comment: @dbc it's age old code I need to support, if I had a choice I would never go with ArrayList and yes every time I know which object to expect in the ArrayList. I have multiple parent objects and each of them have ArrayList members, and for a specific parent class I know what type to expect inside the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance that the `ArrayList` should contain items of a certain type, you can easily create a [`JsonConverter<ArrayList>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-5.0) to serialize and deserialize the `ArrayList` as follows:

```
public class KnownItemTypeArrayListConverter<TItem> : JsonConverter<ArrayList>
{
    public override ArrayList Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        new ArrayList(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TItem>>(ref reader, options));
        
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ArrayList value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Cast<TItem>(), options);
}
```

And then you can use it to serialize and deserialize your `Test` model as follows:

```
var e1 = new Employee { MyProperty = 1, Name = "Yash", };
var e2 = new Employee { MyProperty = 1, Name = "Yash", };
var t = new Test { list = new ArrayList { e1, e2 }, };

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new KnownItemTypeArrayListConverter<Employee>() },
};

var text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(t, options);

var t2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(text, options);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20kkuw).

Alternatively, you can apply the converter to your model by using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=net-5.0):

```
public class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }  
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(KnownItemTypeArrayListConverter<Employee>))]
    public ArrayList list { get; set; }
}
```

(I am using the fully qualified type name to avoid confusion with Newtonsoft's [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).)

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iQsBuX).

That being said, use of `ArrayList` is deprecated.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class.

You might consider upgrading your legacy code to use the following model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }            
    public List<Employee> list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @dbc, I tried to create this converter but a small mistake which resulted in run time exceptions, thanks again!!